# How to remove the underline at the end of the table?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I would like to know how I can remove the underline at the end of the table? I find it ugly...
I don't see  how to remove this?

[image]

[image]

Here is the code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML CSS JS</title>
</head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Confirmation</h4>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close button" aria-describedby="modal-title" (click)="modal.hide()">
    </button>

</div>
<div class="modal-body">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-striped spaceLeft " style="width: 100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Purchase of </th>
                                <td style="min-width: 100%"> 5 Ittroises BE 34120185 </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width: 60%">Valid until</th>
                                <td style="min-width: 100%">01/01/2022 </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="goBack()" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="sendCancelOrderRequest()">Confirmer</button>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want any border, you can set `border:none`.
The border you don't want is applied on td and th of the last tr element, so your selector is `.table tr:last-child th, .table tr:last-child td`

```css
.table tr:last-child th, 
.table tr:last-child td{
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-hover table-striped spaceLeft " style="width: 100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Purchase of </th>
      <td style="min-width: 100%"> 5 Ittroises BE 34120185 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 60%">Valid until</th>
      <td style="min-width: 100%">01/01/2022 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="goBack()" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="sendCancelOrderRequest()">Confirmer</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
              <tr>
                <th style="width: 60%; border-bottom: none;">Valid until</th>
                <td style="min-width: 100%; border-bottom: none;">
                  01/01/2022
                </td>
              </tr>
```

Comment: You can to add css style to th and td => border-bottom: none;

Comment: if the table have more than 1 row all the  border bottoms of td will have 0px and i think that is not the desire output

Comment: If you want to add more informations to your answer, I suggest you to edit it instead of adding comments

Comment: In this particular example, all styles are written inside html

Answer (score 1):

```html
 <style>
   table > tbody > tr:last-child > * { 
      border-bottom-width: 0; 
   }
 </style>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML CSS JS</title>
</head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Confirmation</h4>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close button" aria-describedby="modal-title" (click)="modal.hide()">
    </button>

</div>
<div class="modal-body">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-striped spaceLeft " style="width: 100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Purchase of </th>
                                <td style="min-width: 100%"> 5 Ittroises BE 34120185 </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width: 60%">Valid until</th>
                                <td style="min-width: 100%">01/01/2022 </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="goBack()" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="sendCancelOrderRequest()">Confirmer</button>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That border came from the tr of the table so you can add:

```
   tr:last-child{
       border-bottom: none;
   }
```

im using the pseudo selector "`last-child`" because all the tr would have 0px border bottom without it

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS or style tags todo that depends on what you want - simple sample below

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML CSS JS</title>
</head>
<style>

tr.no-bottom-border td {border-bottom: none}
tr.no-bottom-border th {border-bottom: none}
</style>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Confirmation</h4>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close button" aria-describedby="modal-title" (click)="modal.hide()">
    </button>

</div>
<div class="modal-body">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-striped spaceLeft " style="width: 100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Purchase of </th>
                                <td style="min-width: 100%"> 5 Ittroises BE 34120185 </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="no-bottom-border">
                                <th style="width: 60%">Valid until</th>
                                <td style="min-width: 100%">01/01/2022 </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="goBack()" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="sendCancelOrderRequest()">Confirmer</button>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```